# Alignment in nested align

Tags: equations, align, braces

How can I align equations in nested align ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{flexisym}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    CT_i = \left\{\begin {aligned}
        &CT_{i1} = \tau \\
        &CT_{i2} = H(M).e(g, g)^{s\alpha} \\
        &CT_{i3} = h^s \\
        &CT_{i4} = H(M)^{t.H_1(ID_{Ui})} \\
        &CT_{i5} = H(M)^{t.H_1(ID_{ESP_i})} \\
        &\left.\begin{aligned}
            &CT_{i6} = g^{q_y(0)} \\
            &CT_{i7} = H(attr(y))^{q_y(0)}
        \end{aligned}\right\}\forall j \in   \mathbb{A}_{Ui}
    \end{aligned}\right.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

In this case, last two lines are not aligned with rest of the lines (alignment at C, = g/h).

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

with use of the `cases` and `rcases` environment from the  `mathtools` package. without any ampersands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,% for rcases, also load amsmath
            amssymb}  % amsfonts is loaded by amssymb
%\usepackage{flexisym}% not needed in this MWE

\begin{document}
\[
CT_i = \begin{cases}
    CT_{i1} = \tau \\
    CT_{i2} = H(M).e(g, g)^{s\alpha} \\
    CT_{i3} = h^s \\
    CT_{i4} = H(M)^{t.H_1(ID_{Ui})} \\
    CT_{i5} = H(M)^{t.H_1(ID_{ESP_i})} \\
\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\begin{rcases}
    CT_{i6}  = g^{q_y(0)} \\
    CT_{i7}  = H(attr(y))^{q_y(0)}
\end{rcases}\forall j \in   \mathbb{A}_{Ui}
        \end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The meaning of dots in your equations is not clear, so in above MWE I left them as you use. It might be, that you instead them like to have `\cdot˙:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,% for rcases, also load amsmath
            amssymb}  % amsfonts is loaded by amssymb
%\usepackage{flexisym}% not needed in this MWE

\begin{document}
\[
CT_i = \begin{cases}
    CT_{i1} = \tau \\
    CT_{i2} = H(M)\cdot e(g, g)^{s\alpha} \\
    CT_{i3} = h^s \\
    CT_{i4} = H(M)^{t\cdot H_1(ID_{U_i})} \\
    CT_{i5} = H(M)^{t\cdot H_1(ID_{\mathrm{ESP}_i})} \\
\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
\begin{rcases}
    CT_{i6}  = g^{q_y(0)} \\
    CT_{i7}  = H\bigl(\mathrm{attr}(y)\bigr)^{q_y(0)}
\end{rcases}\forall j \in   \mathbb{A}_{Ui}
        \end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: There's still a misalignment; try adding `\kern-\nulldelimiterspace` before `\begin{rcases}`

Comment: @egreg, indeed! you see better than I do. corrected with `\!` (in hope that gives the same result as `\kern-\nulldelimiterspace`

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: to be hones, i don't observe difference, but i correct answer as you suggest.

Comment: There is a difference of 0.46663pt, which is noticeable: `\!` backs up 1.66663pt, whereas `\nulldelimiterspace` is 1.2pt.

Comment: @egreg, thank you very much! i learn something new :-)